# Shouldn't a compressor automatically stop compressing on a predefined PSI level?

Tags: compressor

I just received a new E.C.SMART 25/2500 DARI compressor.
It came without any owner manual, and I couldn't find a manual on the net.
When I turn it on, the main PSI level goes to the red zone and doesn't stop increasing.
Shouldn't it stop automatically on a predefined PSI level ?

Comment: It should have a regulator knob near the pressure gauge.  Try turning it counter-clockwise.

Comment: @Comintern There's no knob next to the big pressure gauge, only next to the small

Comment: I'd try contacting the manufacturer to see if they can get you a manual. Try infomail@daricompressors.it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dari Smart 25/2500 Compressor. 2HP Single Stage, Max 116psi

From the picture, it has a pressure switch, a tank gauge, regulator and regulator output pressure gauge.

The compressor should run till the tank is up to max pressure (116psi) and shut off. What is the Red Zone pressure? Usually Red means Dead and it sounds like the pressure switch has a failure and is not shutting the compressor off before going overpressure.

Amazing that no manuals are available online, I'd use the contact form on their website to see if you can have them email you an electronic equivalent if it's available.

[image]

Closeup

[image]

1. Pressure Shutoff Switch -- Cuts off compressor motor when maximum pressure is reached to prevent over-stressing pump and components.
2. Main Tank pressure -- maximum level reached is controlled by Pressure Switch, operation in the red zone indicates switch failure.
3. Regulator Output Pressure Gauge -- Shows the regulated output pressure
4. Pressure Regulator -- Use the knob on the pressure regulator to set pressure on the Output Pressure Gauge, set to pressure recommended by tool or paint sprayer attached to the compressor

Answer (score 0):

It should. Also after you pass some pressure and the motor did not shut down, safety pressure relief valve should open to prevent your container from exploding.

Most likely pressure regulator is not working properly, or is badly adjusted. Maybe regulator works OK, but contactor is stuck. Lastly, maybe your pressure gouge is of showing larger pressure than actual, and you have leak somewhere and compressor never reaches shutoff pressure because of it.

Either way I would suggest that you take your compressor to service, since exploding compressor pressure vessels are not fun.